# how to pass multiple location in leaflet map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, vue.js, leaflet

i need to  display multi marker in leaflet map using vuejs. and i also need to chcnge marker image i have given code below only for single maker.

```
          mounted () {
            //    L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'assets/vendor/leaflet' TODO: make it work with webpack
            Leaflet.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/images'

            let map = Leaflet.map(this.$refs['mapElement']).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)

            Leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            }).addTo(map)

            Leaflet.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)

              .openPopup()
          },
```

below is my api output data

```
   [[51.4, -0.03],[53.5, -0.39],[52.5, -0.39]]
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use the solution [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9150014) with your API output.

```
var res =  [[51.4, -0.03],[53.5, -0.39],[52.5, -0.39]];

for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            marker = new L.marker(res[i])
                .addTo(map);
        }
```

Hope that answers your question.